# Perdiodic Event in class, not blocking the thread, threading timer

Tags: c#, .net

i am quite new to C# and programming at all. Currently i occure following Problem and i hope you can help me.I have a program currently looking like this:

```
public class myClass
{
    public void SetSomething(Parameter)
    {
        ///Here something is set
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        ///Here something is done using paramaters from the SetSomething()
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        DoSomething(); //this needs to be done periodicly after started one time
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        //Stop doing something periodically
    }
}
```

From an outside function (user entry via form) SetSomething, Run and Stop are called. DoSomething has to run periodically if Run() was called until Stop() is called. Problem is: This shouldn't block the current thread. So a Sleep(x) is not an Option. SetSomething parameters change very frequent so calling Stop() before and another Run() afterwards is not an option to change DoSomething()'s parameters

Most likely Timers are the perfect solution here. But as this program is used on WinCE6 with compact.Net framework System.Timers namespace is not available. I tried using system.windows.forms.Timer but this wont trigger the given event ever (maybe because it is in the wrong thread. i didn't write the form and mustn't change it). So my only option seems to be System.threading.timer.

I tried to get this running for multiple hours but at one point all my tries come to an end: as i need to start and stop the timer from different methods i need to declare it outside the method. Problem is: i can only declare static methods as delegate here. if the method is static, i cant change the parameters used by the timers delegate method.

i know my English and explanation aren't the best, but i hope you can get my point. How can i realize this functionality? Problem is: i mustn't change the function calling my class.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to declare your timer static? You shouldn't. Just declare it as a regular variable in your class.

Comment: I am not declaring my Timer himself static. i need to give him a static mathod as his delegate function. Here is my code für the timer:`TempLoop TheTempLoop = new TempLoop();

        AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        TimerCallback tcb = TheTempLoop.DoLoop;

        Timer TheLoopTimer = new Timer(tcb, autoEvent, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);`

Comment: No, you don't need to "give him" a delegate pointing at a static method? (Probably, anyway, but if that's the case it's really, really, really bad code)

Comment: As i need to write the code outside of a method (cause the timer.change method needs to be called in Run() and Stop()) i need to declare the timer in the head of the class (outside of a method) and there, i only can "give him" a delegate to a static method.

Comment: I don't get the details, but your problem isn't that you have to have the timer declared static, the problem is that you have other code that need to call a static method. That's the problem. Solve that

Comment: `public class MyClass
    {

        TempLoop TheTempLoop = new TempLoop();

        AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        TimerCallback tcb = TheTempLoop.DoLoop;

        Timer TheLoopTimer = new Timer(tcb, autoEvent, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

       //method below here}` is giving me the compiler error: Error `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property`